# Call Forwarding and Callee ID

Tags: twilio

I would like to forward call from mobile phone numbers to a single Twilio number (using regular carrier forwarding functionnality).

I would like to know if there is any way to get the original callee id from the incoming call on the Twilio number (i.e. the mobile number of the original recipient of the forwarded call).

Said differently, I would like to be able, when I receive the call on Twilio, to make the difference between calls forwarded from the number A and calls forwarded from number B.

If this is not possible like this, is there any other option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to not forward the calls to Twilio and call the Twilio number directly. The ability to capture the original called number is carrier dependent and not reliable.

ForwardedFrom - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters

You could also forward the call to Twilio via SIP (rather then over the Public Switched Telephone Network), and possibly pass an [X-Header](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sending-sip) with the original Caller ID, but that is most likely not possible with your existing carrier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I need to have multiple user so i cannot use the Twilio number because I need to discriminate between them. Any ideas how Visual Voice Mail apps that work thanks to call forwarding do manage this ? Many are free even in countries where the DID (number) prices are quite high. Hard to see how they can be profitable.

Comment: For exemple, here is a description for Youmail : With our YouMail Essential plan, many accounts all forward to a general access number. Once a call reaches this point, our system identifies your phone number and deposits your messages into your account. Even though multiple people may be forwarding to the same deposit number, they only have access to their own messages. Deposit numbers are usually specific to a carrier or region so don't be surprised if you ever meet someone near by with the same number. Any idea how does this work ?